# Yoast SEO: convert og:description to meta name descriptions?

Tags: wordpress, seo, meta-tags, yoast

I am working on a website with 100+ pages and somehow I forgot all about the meta descriptions. Yoast however, has automatically added "og:description" tags which actually has the content I need for meta name="description" on each page. So how can I get or duplicate the og:descriptions into meta name descriptions? Something to do with setting up the Yoast page meta templates? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a template for meta description in Yoast (SEO->Search Appearance->Content types). This will set meta descriptions for all pages unless they are individually overridden.

Comment: Yes, but what tag should I put there that will pick up the og:description and replicate it as a meta description?

Comment: I don't know what specifically is in the og:description field on your site, but it might be the %%excerpt%%. You can start typing % and you will start seeing a list of suggestions. Here you can see all the snippets available: https://yoast.com/help/list-available-snippet-variables-yoast-seo/

Comment: I have found a custom variable which has what I need: _yoast_wpseo_metadesc - so I tried putting %%cf___yoast_wpseo_metadesc%% into the Yoast Meta description box - but it doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: That's where the input for the meta description is stored, so I guess that will not work.  But if this variable has what you need, it should be outputted in the meta description field along with og:description. Do you have any other plugins that might cause a conflict?

Comment: I don't see any plugin that might cause a conflict. Sorry, but I'm no expert on Yoast. Should a meta description be automatically generated? That would easily solve this problem I guess. In the source code I see the message from Yoast:

<!-- Admin only notice: this page does not show a meta description because it does not have one, either write it for this page specifically or go into the [SEO - Search Appearance] menu and set up a template. -->

Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Yes, you can set the template in the Search Appearance field, and it will populate automatically on your pages. Do you see the same message in the source code if you enter %%excerpt%% in the meta description field for pages in Search Appearance?

Comment: Yes, I see the same message.

Comment: Then the meta description field is not working as expected, I think. You can try to troubleshoot this specific problem with Yoast Meta description field, also check out the snippet preview in the Yoast Meta box on a page to see if any changes are reflected there.